# CoreMotion API and Motion Permission

Tags: ios, ios7, uikit, core-motion, apple-m7

When using data from the M7 motion coprocessor on the iPhone 5S I have seen that some classes make the user grant permission to the app, (a bit like they do for GPS use or photo Library)

Does anyone know which core motion classes require the user to allow motion access as I want to avoid this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMMotionActivityManager` for sure!